# C++ - No directory found when executing makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

**OS**: Windows 10 - **Compiler**: mingw64

I have a very simple program that uses OpenGL. My only file, `main.cpp`, is the following:

```
/*
 * OGL02Animation.cpp: 3D Shapes with animation
 */
//#include <windows.h>  // for MS Windows
#include <GL/glut.h>  // GLUT, include glu.h and gl.h

/* Global variables */
char title[] = "3D Shapes with animation";
GLfloat anglePyramid = 0.0f;  // Rotational angle for pyramid [NEW]
GLfloat angleCube = 0.0f;     // Rotational angle for cube [NEW]
int refreshMills = 15;        // refresh interval in milliseconds [NEW]

/* Initialize OpenGL Graphics */
void initGL() {
   glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Set background color to black and opaque
   glClearDepth(1.0f);                   // Set background depth to farthest
   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);   // Enable depth testing for z-culling
   glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);    // Set the type of depth-test
   glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);   // Enable smooth shading
   glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);  // Nice perspective corrections
}

/* Handler for window-repaint event. Called back when the window first appears and
   whenever the window needs to be re-painted. */
void display() {
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear color and depth buffers
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);     // To operate on model-view matrix

   // Render a color-cube consisting of 6 quads with different colors
   glLoadIdentity();                 // Reset the model-view matrix
   glTranslatef(1.5f, 0.0f, -7.0f);  // Move right and into the screen
   glRotatef(angleCube, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  // Rotate about (1,1,1)-axis [NEW]

   glBegin(GL_QUADS);                // Begin drawing the color cube with 6 quads
      // Top face (y = 1.0f)
      // Define vertices in counter-clockwise (CCW) order with normal pointing out
      glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);     // Green
      glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f);
      glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f);

      // Bottom face (y = -1.0f)
      glColor3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);     // Orange
      glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
      glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

      // Front face  (z = 1.0f)
      glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);     // Red
      glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
      glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

      // Back face (z = -1.0f)
      glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);     // Yellow
      glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);
      glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);

      // Left face (x = -1.0f)
      glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);     // Blue
      glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);

      // Right face (x = 1.0f)
      glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);     // Magenta
      glVertex3f(1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);
      glVertex3f(1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
      glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
      glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
   glEnd();  // End of drawing color-cube

   // Render a pyramid consists of 4 triangles
   glLoadIdentity();                  // Reset the model-view matrix
   glTranslatef(-1.5f, 0.0f, -6.0f);  // Move left and into the screen
   glRotatef(anglePyramid, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);  // Rotate about the (1,1,0)-axis [NEW]

   glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);           // Begin drawing the pyramid with 4 triangles
      // Front
      glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);     // Red
      glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
      glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);     // Green
      glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
      glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);     // Blue
      glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

      // Right
      glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);     // Red
      glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
      glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);     // Blue
      glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
      glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);     // Green
      glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

      // Back
      glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);     // Red
      glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
      glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);     // Green
      glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
      glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);     // Blue
      glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

      // Left
      glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);       // Red
      glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
      glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);       // Blue
      glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);
      glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);       // Green
      glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);
   glEnd();   // Done drawing the pyramid

   glutSwapBuffers();  // Swap the front and back frame buffers (double buffering)

   // Update the rotational angle after each refresh [NEW]
   anglePyramid += 0.2f;
   angleCube -= 0.15f;
}

/* Called back when timer expired [NEW] */
void timer(int value) {
   glutPostRedisplay();      // Post re-paint request to activate display()
   glutTimerFunc(refreshMills, timer, 0); // next timer call milliseconds later
}

/* Handler for window re-size event. Called back when the window first appears and
   whenever the window is re-sized with its new width and height */
void reshape(GLsizei width, GLsizei height) {  // GLsizei for non-negative integer
   // Compute aspect ratio of the new window
   if (height == 0) height = 1;                // To prevent divide by 0
   GLfloat aspect = (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height;

   // Set the viewport to cover the new window
   glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

   // Set the aspect ratio of the clipping volume to match the viewport
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);  // To operate on the Projection matrix
   glLoadIdentity();             // Reset
   // Enable perspective projection with fovy, aspect, zNear and zFar
   gluPerspective(45.0f, aspect, 0.1f, 100.0f);
}

/* Main function: GLUT runs as a console application starting at main() */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   glutInit(&argc, argv);            // Initialize GLUT
   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE); // Enable double buffered mode
   glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);   // Set the window's initial width & height
   glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50); // Position the window's initial top-left corner
   glutCreateWindow(title);          // Create window with the given title
   glutDisplayFunc(display);       // Register callback handler for window re-paint event
   glutReshapeFunc(reshape);       // Register callback handler for window re-size event
   initGL();                       // Our own OpenGL initialization
   glutTimerFunc(0, timer, 0);     // First timer call immediately [NEW]
   glutMainLoop();                 // Enter the infinite event-processing loop
   return 0;
}
```

This is the `makefile` that I created:

```
# Makefile

INCLUDE = -I"C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\include"

LIBRARIES = -L"C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\lib" -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lm -lXi -lXmu -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lfreeglut

COMPILER = g++ --std=c++17
COMPILERFLAGS = -no-pie $(INCLUDE)


PROGRAM =   test

SOURCE =    main.cpp

OBJECT =    main.o


.cc.o: $(SOURCE)
    $(COMPILER) -c $(COMPILERFLAGS) $<

all: $(PROGRAM)

$(PROGRAM): $(OBJECT) $(SOURCE)
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILERFLAGS) -o $(PROGRAM) $(OBJECT) $(LIBRARIES)

clean:
    -rm -rf core *.o *~ .*~ $(PROGRAM)
```

As IDE I am using CodeBlocks. When I compile and run the program on the IDE, **it works fine.** Also, when I build and run the program in the command line, **it works fine too:**

```
g++ main.cpp -o output.exe -I"C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\include" -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lfreeglut
```

The only problem comes, when I use the gnu command `make`. When I do `make test` in the `cmd`, I obtain the following error:

> g++    -c -o main.o main.cpp main.cpp:5:10: fatal error: GL/glut.h: No
>   such file or directory  #include   // GLUT, include glu.h
>   and gl.h
>             ^~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated. make: *** [: main.o] Error 1

Are the libraries and paths not well defined in the `makefile`? I cannot fully understand why `make` does not work.

Thank you.

Comment: You didn't add the include path for GL. What's the path to GL/glut.h?

Comment: C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\include\GL

Comment: I can't find this line `g++ -c -o main.o main.cpp` in your makefile? Are you sure that you use the correct Makefile?

Comment: should be this: `$(PROGRAM): $(OBJECT) $(SOURCE)
 $(COMPILER) $(COMPILERFLAGS) -o $(PROGRAM) $(OBJECT) $(LIBRARIES)`, right?

Comment: The output of this line should be `g++ --std=c++17 -no-pie -I"C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\include" -o test -L"C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\lib" -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lm -lXi -lXmu -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lfreeglut`. But the actual output is `g++ -c -o main.o main.cpp`. Currently you are using a different makefile. Your error message can't be produced by the given Makefile. A Makefile must be named exactly `Makefile` with an uppercase `M`. Or you have to call `make -f makefile`

Answer (score 2):

You defined a rule `.cc.o` which defines compilation using your own variable names.
However, your file is name `main.cpp`, so it will use the default rule:

```
.cpp.o:
    $(COMPILE.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

with the following default definitions:

```
COMPILE.cpp = $(COMPILE.cc)
COMPILE.cc = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
OUTPUT_OPTION = -o $@
```

So either change the filename of `main.cpp` to `main.cc`, the definition of `COMPILE.cpp`, or the definition of the `.cpp.o` target. Alternatively, you can add your flags to the default variable names and drop the .cc.o rule.